# C++ Novice attempt at Loops

Tags: c++

I am working on my first assignment for C++. I have some history in coding in Java but issues I am having with C++ is hard for me to correct.
The code I have  "works" but debugging I think it isn't doing what I really want it to do. I tried to do a do while loop:

```
// GuessNumber.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x;
    int numberToGuess = 53;
    cout << "Enter number between 0 and 100: ";
    cin >> x;

    do
    {
        if (x < numberToGuess)
        {
            cout << "Guess is too low, try again: ";
            cin >> x;
        }
        else if (x > numberToGuess)
        {
            cout << "Guess is too high, try again: ";
            cin >> x;
        }
    } while (x == numberToGuess);
    {
        cout << "You win " << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to reprompt the user to input data again but whenever I try to test it out the program just closes on me.
Any advice would be greatly appericated

Comment: Put the code in the question. Thanks

Comment: Just read it out loud. Whatever is between the brackets has to be done when exactly? While ...

Comment: Looks like you need to brush up on the syntax for [`do {...} while()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exit condition seems wrong. You iterate, or keep asking the user for the value, while the given value does not guess correctly the number.

Change

```
} while (x == numberToGuess);
```

into

```
} while (x != numberToGuess);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was able to get it to loop. However, I am curious was could I have done this without a do -while loop?

Comment: @DeepThroat You need a loop. Either Do..while or a simple while loop would work. For a while loop just move your condition. while (x != numberToGuess){......}

Answer (score 4):

I think you should put `while (x != numberToGuess)` in order for it to continue after the first wrong attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't there be `x != numberToGuess`? You want to repeadately ask user for a number as long as x is different from guessed number. Also I think there is no reason to put cout in brackets {}.